# How to specify default include directory in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, gnu-make

I am new in GCC and I am wondering how to tell the compiler that several include directories need to be specified as default for searching .h files. I read that **-I dir** is the key to accomplish that but doing my makefiles I encounter some problems. For example:

```
include_dir = C:/Users/rmrd001/Documents/Make/GCC/first/mydir/
FLAGS = -I "$(include_dir)"

func2.o: func2.c func2.h
    gcc $(FLAGS) -c func2.c
```

And I got the error:

**make:*** No rule to make target 'func2.c', needed by 'func2.o'.  Stop.**

The **include_dir** is not the working directory. It is **working_directory/my_dir**.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

`-I` is used for finding include files, but not for finding the main file.  You have to pass an explicit path to the main file.

Answer (score 0):

- You can add path with `-I` option right in command line;
- You can specify path with `env` variable `C_INCLUDE_PATH`

Also you can find more info on [gcc official site](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)