# What does "-I" and "-L" mean when prepended to a path?

Tags: c++, macos, path, openssl

When installing openssl using brew, a part of the response is outputted:

```
For compilers to find openssl you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

and the following could be used to compile a C++ file.

g++ file.cpp -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include

What is the -I and the -L for?

Comment: `-I` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455042 `-L` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836423

Answer (score 8):

`-L` means the path is a dir which contains **L**ibraries for linking (adds the path to the set of dirs the linker will search)

`-I` means there are header files to **I**nclude in the given dir.